How to include fields with null values in Netflix DGS Graphql response
We are using NetflixDGS with spring-boot to implement rest API. Say my API response has to return below object
{
"name": "Abc",
"age": "25",
"place": null
}
But I am getting only below response.
{
"name": "Abc",
"age": "25"
}
This is impacting my down stream application. Even though the value for "place" field is null, I need to have this field in the response.
Is there a way to override Netflix DGS framework behaviour to return all the fields we are requesting though the values are null ?
